# How to convert custom attribute from order item to invoice item?

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, sales-order

I am creating a module to add a additional field (which is a custom product attribute) for invoice.

I have added the custom attribute for the product and then it is converted to quote item, also it is converted to order item. But I'm not able to convert it to invoice item from the order item. I have added the field for this attribute in **sales_flat_invoice_item** table. Even then, it is not getting converted to invoice item from order item.

In my config.xml, I have tried like below

```
<fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote_item>
                <revenue_account_number>
                    <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
                </revenue_account_number>
            </sales_convert_quote_item>
            <sales_convert_order_item>
                <revenue_account_number>
                    <to_quote_item>*</to_quote_item>
                    <to_invoice_item>*</to_invoice_item>
                </revenue_account_number>
            </sales_convert_order_item>
 </fieldsets>
```

Can anyone help on this please?

Comment: Seams you are doing it right. Did you clear the cache?

Comment: I have disabled the cache already.